# Regex[] throwing exception on run

Tags: c#, regex

The following code throws

> The type initializer for 'ConsoleApplication1.Program' threw an exception.

on the line

```
public static Regexp[] keepers = { ... };
```

Why is this wrong and how can I fix it?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static String output = "";
        public static Regex[] keepers = { 
                                            new Regex(@"using(?<everythingElse> [a-zA-Z.]+;)"),
                                            new Regex(@"namespace(?<everythingElse> [a-zA-Z._]+)"),
                                            new Regex(@"class(?<everythingElse> [a-zA-Z._]+)"),
                                            new Regex(@"(public|private)? ?(static)? ?(?<type> String|void|int|Double)(" + Regex.Escape("[") + "?" + Regex.Escape("]") + "?" + "(?<functionName> [a-z_]+)(?<params> [^\r\n]+)")
                                        };
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {}}}
```

Comment: Read the InnerException.

Comment: Some of the regexes in the array is wrong. If you remove the initializer, and try to initialize all of them in Main(), you will find out what one.

Comment: Why do you write that really bloated `" + Regex.Escape("[") + "` instead of just `\[`?

Comment: @m.buettner \[ may work but if you use \] it errors and I like to do things the same every time so I don't end up with different conventions all over the place

Comment: @JordanTrainor What do you mean? What I meant was, why do you use the escape function and concatenation (which is less readable and incurs runtime overhead) instead of just escaping the character yourself with a backslash.

Comment: the following code will error because its an unknown escape character new Regex("\\]")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 4. regex

```
@"(public|private)? ?(static)? ?(?<type> String|void|int|Double)(
```

opens a ( at the end. This is not being closed!

Answer (score 6):

**Always** look at the full exception. Here it is in your case (reformatted slightly):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
'ConsoleApplication1.Program' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException:
 parsing "(public|private)? ?(static)? ?(?<type> String|void|int|Double)(\[?]?
 (?<functionName> [a-z_]+)(?<params> [^]+)" - Not enough )'s.
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.ScanRegex()
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.Parse(String re, RegexOptions op)
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex..ctor(String pattern, RegexOptions options, TimeSpan matchTimeout, Boolean useCache)
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex..ctor(String pattern)
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

So you can see:

- It's in the fourth regular expression
- You've got a problem with your brackets

Next up, I would try to break that large regular expression up into small ones, and work out *why* you've got an unmatched bracket. I suspect this:

```
"(" + Regex.Escape("[") + "?" + Regex.Escape("]") + "?"
```

should be:

```
"(" + Regex.Escape("[") + "?" + Regex.Escape("]") + ")?"
```

... but you should check.

Comment: +0  what is the problem with his brackets?

Comment: Yeah, he's opening one in front of the concatenation that is never closed.

Comment: @SamIam: I think *that* is reasonable to leave to the OP... but I'll make some suggestions.

Comment: Hey, I had a similar error earlier and never realised there was an inner exception with something _useful_.

Comment: @m.buettner: Yup, that was my thought too.

Comment: @Rawling: So long as you always print the full exception, never just the message or just the stack trace, you should always be able to see this kind of thing

Comment: @Jon I was in the debugger, I always forget to check the InnerException.